# How to use XPath get content of same field?

Tags: python, regex, xpath

I am a beginner of Xpath and just can not match content correctly. Here is my question:

How to use XPath to get the date '2010.09.07' (after 申请日：) and '2009.09.03'? Actually, there are 10 same items (g_item) below g_list hierarchy, here I just listed two of them. I try to copy Xpath from Chorm, while it doesn't work.

Also, I try to use regex as below，however, it just matches the first one. Is there a way to return all dates of all items?

Thanks!

```
s.find(string=('申请日：')).find_next().text.replace('\n', '').strip()
```

```html
<div class="g_list">



                <div class="g_item">
                <div class="g_tit">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="g_li0">
                            <input id="CN201010274593.21" name="recordno" type="checkbox" value="CN201010274593.2" pnm="CN102403785B" sysid="B58C6C20BB7D5998B03811E0866F5981" appid="201010274593.2" sectionName="FMSQ" onclick="checkall()"/></li>
                            <input id="tifPath1" name="tifPath" type="hidden" tifvalue="BOOKS/SD/2014/20140716/201010274593.2,12,CN201010274593.2" xmlvalue="FMSQ,CN201010274593.2,2014.07.16" pdfvalue="Granted_patent_for_invention/2014/20140716/CN102403785B/PDF_PID/CN102010000274593CN00001024037850BPDFZH20140716CN008.PDF,CN201010274593.2" pdfvalue2="CN102403785B,2014.07.16"/>
                        <li class="g_li" onclick="viewDetail(0)" style="cursor:pointer" name='patti'  title="电源管理装置及其电源管理方法">
                            1.电源管理装置及其电源管理方法</li>
                        <li class="g_li1">发明授权 </li>





                                   <li class="g_li2 cor3">无效</li>




                        <li class="g_li3"><a href="javascript:noAction();" onclick="downloadRecord('B58C6C20BB7D5998B03811E0866F5981','FMSQ');">下载</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="g_cont">
                    <div class="g_cont_left">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>申请号：</span> <a href="javascript:viewDetail(0);">CN201010274593.2</a> </td>
                                <td><span>申请日：</span> 2010.09.07 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>公开(公告)号：</span> CN102403785B </td>
                                <td><span>公开(公告)日：</span> 2014.07.16 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>同日申请：

                                </td>
                                <td><span>分案原申请号：

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="width:610px;word-break:break-all;"><span>申请(专利权)人：</span> 鸿富锦精密工业（深圳）有限公司;鸿海精密工业股份有限公司 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"  style="width:610px;word-break:break-all;"><span>分类号：</span> H02J13/00(2006.01) </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td  colspan="2"  style="width:610px;word-break:break-all;"><span>优先权：</span></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>



                                   <td colspan="2"><span>摘要：</span><span name="patab" style="font-weight:normal"></span>
                                   <a name="abmtlink"  href="javascript:return false;"  style="color:blue">机器翻译</a></td>


                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g_cont_rig" id="pic1">



                          <a href="http://pic.cnipr.com/XmlData/SQ\20140716\201010274593.2/201010274593.gif"><img name="tifpath"  src="http://pic.cnipr.com/XmlData/SQ\20140716\201010274593.2/201010274593.gif" class="imgstyle"/></a>


                  </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="g_item">
                <div class="g_tit">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="g_li0">
                            <input id="CN200910171675.12" name="recordno" type="checkbox" value="CN200910171675.1" pnm="CN102006581B" sysid="E7025BBD105585DF6CE4193E52ECC322" appid="200910171675.1" sectionName="FMSQ" onclick="checkall()"/></li>
                            <input id="tifPath2" name="tifPath" type="hidden" tifvalue="BOOKS/SD/2013/20130911/200910171675.1,21,CN200910171675.1" xmlvalue="FMSQ,CN200910171675.1,2013.09.11" pdfvalue="Granted_patent_for_invention/2013/20130911/CN102006581B/PDF_PID/CN102009000171675CN00001020065810BPDFZH20130911CN008.PDF,CN200910171675.1" pdfvalue2="CN102006581B,2013.09.11"/>
                        <li class="g_li" onclick="viewDetail(1)" style="cursor:pointer" name='patti'  title="IP地址强制续约的方法及装置">
                            2.IP地址强制续约的方法及装置</li>
                        <li class="g_li1">发明授权 </li>





                                   <li class="g_li2 cor3">无效</li>




                        <li class="g_li3"><a href="javascript:noAction();" onclick="downloadRecord('E7025BBD105585DF6CE4193E52ECC322','FMSQ');">下载</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="g_cont">
                    <div class="g_cont_left">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>申请号：</span> <a href="javascript:viewDetail(1);">CN200910171675.1</a> </td>
                                <td><span>申请日：</span> 2009.09.03 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>公开(公告)号：</span> CN102006581B </td>
                                <td><span>公开(公告)日：</span> 2013.09.11 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>同日申请：

                                </td>
                                <td><span>分案原申请号：

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="width:610px;word-break:break-all;"><span>申请(专利权)人：</span> 中兴通讯股份有限公司 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"  style="width:610px;word-break:break-all;"><span>分类号：</span> H04W8/08(2009.01);H04W36/14(2009.01);H04W84/12(2009.01);H04L29/12(2006.01) </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td  colspan="2"  style="width:610px;word-break:break-all;"><span>优先权：</span></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>



                                   <td colspan="2"><span>摘要：</span><span name="patab" style="font-weight:normal"></span>
                                   <a name="abmtlink"  href="javascript:return false;"  style="color:blue">机器翻译</a></td>


                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g_cont_rig" id="pic2">



                          <a href="http://pic.cnipr.com/XmlData/SQ/20130911/200910171675.1/200910171675.gif"><img name="tifpath"  src="http://pic.cnipr.com/XmlData/SQ/20130911/200910171675.1/200910171675.gif" class="imgstyle"/></a>


                  </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has multiple markup validation errors, you can check for the errors using [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options). However, if you fix the following errors is possible to parse the string using `lxml`.

> Unclosed element span.
> From line 43, column 37; to line 43, column 42 
> Unclosed element span.
> From line 46, column 37; to line 46, column 42 
> Unclosed element span.
> From line 119, column 37; to line 119, column 42 
> Unclosed element span.
> From line 122, column 37; to line 122, column 42 
> Stray end tag div.
> From line 159, column 5; to line 159, column 10

```
from lxml import etree

pageHTML = """
<div class="g_list">
        <div class="g_item">
        ...
        ...
"""

root = etree.fromstring(pageHTML)

dateList = root.xpath("//*[@class='g_cont_left']/table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()")
print(dateList)

#[' 2010.09.07 ', ' 2009.09.03 ']
```

If you still want to use a regex (which I would advise against, given the whole discussion about applying regular expressions over an HTML, XML, etc. or use a parser specific for that grammar) you can define a capturing group allowing only digits and a literal `.` (`([\d\.]+)`) surrounded by the exact words you expect to find.

```
import re

pageHTML = """
<div class="g_list">
        <div class="g_item">
        ...
        ...
"""
date_Regex = re.findall("申请日：\s*</span>\s*([\d\.]+)\s*</td>", pageHTML)
print(date_Regex)

# ['2010.09.07', '2009.09.03']
```